# Make a WPF ListBox comma separate values

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, listbox

I have a ListBox that looks like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Fruits}">
    <!--Make the items wrap--> 
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel></WrapPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, StringFormat=' {0},'}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

This gives me a list like this:

> Oranges, Grapes, Bananas,

But what I want is:

> Oranges, Grapes, Bananas

(no trailing comma)

**Any one have an idea on how to remove the trailing comma?**

Comment: Did my answer work for you or you still looking for something else?

Comment: @RohitVats - Thanks for the answer.  That is what I used.  (I was hoping for a easier way, but that worked well.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be achieved using [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) to determine whether its `last item in a listBox and there by updating StringFormat on your binding using data trigger in XAML`.

Create a converter to determine if value is last item in listbox -

```
public class IsLastItemInContainerConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                          CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DependencyObject item = (DependencyObject)value;
        ItemsControl ic = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(item);

        return ic.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(item) ==
                                                        ic.Items.Count - 1;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                              CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now modify your XAML and add trigger on DataTemplate to remove comma from StringFormat on your TextBlock -

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Fruits}">
   <ListBox.Resources>
      <local:IsLastItemInContainerConverter
             x:Key="IsLastItemInContainerConverter"/>
   </ListBox.Resources>
   <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <WrapPanel/>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock"
                    Text="{Binding Name, StringFormat=' {0},'}" />
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                                               Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                               AncestorType=ListBoxItem},
                                               Converter={StaticResource IsLastItemInContainerConverter}}" 
                             Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Text" TargetName="textBlock"
                            Value="{Binding Name, StringFormat=' {0}'}"/>
                 </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
       </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you refactor your code, you can make a string that has your desired result very easily:

```
string.Join(", ", Fruits) // e.g. Oranges, Grapes, Bananas
```

E.g. you could have:

```
// on your binding object
public string FruitString { get { return string.Join(", ", Fruits); } }
// in your XAML
<TextBlock Text="{Binding FruitString}" />
```

(or, if the `Fruits` property was of a class you defined, you could override its `ToString()`, which would be a good place to put the `Join` code)

Comment: @gleng good point, assuming that's something he actually needs to do. For now, I don't know if it is, so I'll leave my solution here.

Comment: This will work, but the owner of the "Fruits" object is a common business object in my code.  I was hoping to not have to modify it with a flattened version.  Still if that is the only way, then I can do it.

Comment: I don't see a better way to work with a `ListBox` and make a comma-separated value, since it doesn't seem to care whether an item is first, last, or middle. What about `Fruits`'s type? Would it be better for you to override its `ToString()`?