# Adding list items to observable collection list

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

Hi I am trying to add list items to an observable collection list. 
I have a model where I setup a list property

```
public class DisplayList
{
   public List<string> listItem { get; set; }
}
```

then on my main page I have an observable collection

```
 private ObservableCollection<DisplayList> ListDisplay;
```

which I instantiate on page load

```
 public MainPage()
    {

        this.InitializeComponent();

        location = new ObservableCollection<storeLocations>();
        ListDisplay = new ObservableCollection<DisplayList>();
        // location = manager.getStoreLocations();
        var dbList = db.Bales.Where(b => b.Location != null).Select(b => b.Location).ToList();
        InitialLoad(dbList, null);

    }
```

I am using suggestion boxes and want to filter results based on the selection made. The filtered results then display in a list on screen and this is where I am having a bit of trouble. I get it to display on screen, but it is displaying 
System.Collection.Generic.List'1[S....... instead of the actual item in the list.

I am thinking I am not enumerating properly, but cant seem to pin point the error in my ways.

This is the method that is meant to populate the list based on selection of suggestion box.

```
 public ObservableCollection<DisplayList>BaleList(List<string> CatNo)
    {

        foreach (var item in CatNo)
        {

            ListDisplay.Add(new DisplayList {listItem = CatNo.ToList()});
        }

        lstBales.IsItemClickEnabled = true;

        return ListDisplay;
    }
```

it takes in a parameter of type list which is gotten from the suggestion box. so the parameter value is basically what I want to display in the list on screen. e.g. CP1354-2 and second item CP1355-3 So those values come into the method. I want to apply those values to the observable collection as the listbox control is bound to the observable collection.

**EDIT**
adding binding in XAML

```
  <ListView x:Name="lstBales" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ListDisplay}">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate  x:Name="TemplateListName" x:DataType="data:DisplayList">
                                <Grid>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind listItem}"/>
                                </Grid>

                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
```

Comment: You are binding an object of List typed to the TextBlock. Whereas TextBlock.Text is expecting a string.

Comment: So if I change the object from type list to type string it should solve my issue?

Comment: Yes. Also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733671/make-a-wpf-listbox-comma-separate-values

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. After changing from list to string i still got the same issue, but after a bit of a head scratch I actually make a blunder in the method. 

in the foreach loop... I have put listItem = CatNo.ToList() It should be ListItem = item.ToString and not the CatNo input paramater...

so that in addition to the suggestions about the Datatemplate sorted it out. THANK YOU ALL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ListDisplay.Add(new DisplayList {listItem = CatNo.ToList()});
```

and  `<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind listItem}"/>`

You are binding a list to a `TextBlock` due to which `ToString()`is implicitly called and you don't get the actual values. According to your requirements, you can either change `listItem` to a string or create a nested `ListView`

Comment: Thanks changed to string and also had issue in foreach loop. I set the listitem = CatNo but should have been set = to item.. thanks for the help