# Separate items with a comma inside ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to add commas after each element in my `ItemsControl`. Following this SO post
[Make a WPF ListBox comma separate values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733671/make-a-wpf-listbox-comma-separate-values)
...I've created a converter and am trying to use it in the XAML code but I'm doing something wrong and don't know what.
The `TextBlock` containing `Text=","` is supposed to use the converter to control its own `Visibility`.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding RecipientsNames}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">

    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                <Button x:Name="btnContact" Click="BtnContact_Click"
                        Width="Auto" Height="14" Padding="0" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontSize="12" Margin="0 -2 0 -2"/>
                </Button>

                <TextBlock Text="," FontSize="12" Margin="0 -2 6 -2"
                     Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                     Mode=FindAncestor, 
                     AncestorType=ItemsControlItem},
                     Converter={StaticResource IsLastItemInContainerConverter}}"/>

            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<TextBlock Text="," FontSize="12" Margin="0 -2 6 -2"
                     Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                     Mode=FindAncestor, 
                     AncestorType=ContentPresenter},
                     Converter={StaticResource IsLastItemInContainerConverter}}"/>
```

---

```
public class IsLastItemInContainerConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        FrameworkElement item = (FrameworkElement)value;
        ItemsControl ic = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(item);

        return ic.Items.IndexOf(item.DataContext) == ic.Items.Count - 1 ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```